# SQL Server : create view or procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I'm working on a project with sql server database on it. I have a problem with some query. i have a table:

**Current table:**

```
 Month   | Year   |   EmpID  | Salary 
 ------------------------------------
  1          2016       123     100
  2          2016       123     120 
  3          2016       123     110 
  4          2016       123     150 
  1          2016       456     200 
  2          2016       456     210 
  3          2016       456     225 
  4          2016       456     220
```

And I want to create something with result like this:

**After query table:**

```
EmpID    |  Salary1   |  Salary2 |  Salary3 | Salary4 
123          100          120         110       150
456          200          210         225       220
```

Note : naming salary table based on month table so there will be Salary12

What query should I type? Should I create a view or a stored procedure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices are a view, stored procedure, or stored function.  I see not reason to use a stored procedure -- I think a result set is much more useful when you can use it in another query.

You can use either `pivot` or conditional aggregation for the result.  As a view:

```
create view v_current as
     select c.empid, 
            max(casewhen c.month = 1 then salary end) as salary_01,
            max(casewhen c.month = 2 then salary end) as salary_02,
            . . .
            max(casewhen c.month = 12 then salary end) as salary_12
     from current c
     where c.year = year(getdate())
     group by c.empid;
```

Note:  `month`and `year` are keywords in SQL Server so they are very bad choices for column names.  You should find another name for these columns.

Comment: Yes, actually their real name are Bulan for Month and Tahun for Year. i m just change it in order to make it simple so people who read will understand. Btw, what is the use 'current' in select from for? i got error said Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Current'

Comment: @EndyMooduto ... That is meant to be the table name.